# Building CTC structure calculator for SAAS application

Tags: java, html, reactjs, spring-boot

I am building HR Portal as SAAS application, now am building payroll module.

we have to create different components like(Basic, HRA, travel allowance, mobile allowance, pf, esi, gross and CTC etc). while defining those components componenet value can be type of value or formula based.

If value is formula based,
ex:

1. basic is 40%CTC (Formula)
2. HRA is 80%basic
3. other allowance is 50%Gross
4. travel allowance is IF($location is 'metro', 20%baisc, '20000'), also there is a chance of nested IF conditions

Now my question was how to capture these formula based values in HTML input filed then later how to caliculate actual values of the component.

Its like I should build basic formulas of Excel with in HTML form.

Fornt End : HTML, React
Back End  : Java with Springboot